# Please help with this hard inequality provement

Tags: inequality

Please help to prove this.

Assume $a,b,c,m,n>0$, then we have
$${a\over ma+nb+c}+{b \over  {mb+nc+a}}+{c\over{mc+na+b}}\leq\max\{{3\over m+n+1},{1\over m},{2\over m+\sqrt{n}}\}$$

Thanks.

Comment: Don't you wantto require $m,n>0$?

Comment: Yes. $n$ must be positive. But not so sure on $m$.

Comment: I think $m\geq 0$ otherwise for $a=0, b=c=1, m=-2, n=2$ the claim fails.

Comment: Thanks. Modified accordingly.

Comment: You may want to watch http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785835/how-prove-fraca11a9bc-fracb11b9ca-fracc11c9ab-le-frac17 also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't found a simple method, but on clearing denominators, this would be a third degree cyclic homogeneous polynomial inequality, so the [Theorem 1.1](http://www.emis.de/journals/TJNSA/includes/files/articles/Vol6_Iss2_74--85_Some_strong_sufficient_conditions_f.pdf) is applicable.

Let $\displaystyle f(a, b, c) = \sum_{cyc} \frac{a}{ma+nb+c}$.  To find the maximum of $f$, we need equivalently to find the maximum of $f(1, 1, 1)$ and $f(a, 1, 0)$.  The first is obviously $\dfrac3{m+n+1}$, and for the second, we need the maximum of 
$$g(a) = \frac{a}{ma+n}+\frac{1}{m+a}$$

The simplest way now is by derivatives, and we get $\displaystyle g'(a) = -\frac{(a^2-n)(m^2-n)}{(a+m)^2(am+n)^2}$.
So $g'(a)=0$ has one positive root, $a = \sqrt n$.

From the expression for $g'(a)$ it is clear that if $m^2 < n$, $g$ is increasing beyond that root, so the maximum is $\lim_{a \to \infty} g(a) = \dfrac1m$.  OTOH, if $m^2 > n$, then the maximum is $g(\sqrt n) = \dfrac2{m+\sqrt n}$.

Putting all that together, 
$$f(a) \le \max \left(\frac3{m+n+1}, \frac1m, \frac2{m+\sqrt n}\right)$$
Equality is either when $a=b=c$, or when $m^2 > n$ and $(a, b, c)$ is a cyclic permutation of $(\sqrt n \,t, t, 0)$ for any $t \in \mathbb{R}_+$.

---

N.B.  I haven't seen a complete proof of this Theorem 1.1., though its quite nice.  If any one has an online reference that would be great.

Comment: An outline of the proof for the theorem is in http://gil.ro/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/1/ though incomplete :(

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for the proof. Regarding the theorem I think it origins from an IMO medalist and the theorem seems to be known as the CID (cyclic inequality of degree 3). Yet the form that I found (with a detailed proof) here (http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=1130901) has some slight difference with yours. The proof (in the middle of the page) is using the EMV.

Comment: But I'm still not very clear on how this CID can apply here. Can you give more details? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the links, will go through the proof.  Assuming the theorem is true, it is easy to see how it applies - you are trying to find $k$ s.t. $LHS \le k$.  This on clearing denominators is equivalent to $$\sum_{cyc} a(mb+nc+a)(mc+na+b) \le k \prod_{cyc} (ma+nb+c)$$ which is a cyclic inequality of degree three (in variables $a, b, c$) which is homogeneous.  Hence the theorem is applicable, and we see what value of $k$ makes the conditions hold.

Comment: But from my understanding to apply the theorem it is required that the coeff on $a^3,b^3,c^3$ should be larger than 0. Is that right?

Comment: There is no such condition explicit in the conditions for applying the theorem.

Comment: Yes. You are right.